# What does it mean for a family of functions $\{f_n\}$ to be bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$\{f_n\}$ is a family of functions continuous on the interval $(0,1)$. I'm forgetting how to define what it means for $\{f_n\}$ to be bounded and my textbook/google searches aren't providing what I need.

Is it
$$\sup_{0< x< 1}|f_n(x)|\leq K$$
for some $K$ and for all $n$?

Comment: Yes, that would be also how I would understand it.

Comment: If you interpret $(f_n)$ as a sequence in the metric space $C([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ with the sup norm and apply the definition that a sequence is bounded if the set of it's terms is bounded, then you get that there exists $M > 0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $||f_n|| \leq M$. This matches what you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ambiguous. There are several interpretations:

**Pointwise bounded:** For all $x\in (0,1)$, $\sup_n |f_n(x)| < \infty$ .

**Uniformly bounded:** $\sup_n \|f_n\|_\infty < \infty$ where $\|f_n\|_\infty := \sup_{x \in (0,1)} |f(x)|$.

**Entrywise bounded:** For all $n$, $f_n$ is bounded.

I guess the second interpretation is the most likely, but really one cannot tell without context.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Unfortunately the problem doesn't offer context. It's a multi-part problem where we establish sufficient conditions for uniform continuity, uniform equicontinuity and equicontinuity, then the final question is which if any make the set bounded. No mention of uniform, pointwise etc.

Comment: @c_gnar In the context of uniform continuity and similar concepts, definitely go for the second interpretation. Btw, this coincides with your suggestion above. I just worded it differently because I like the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm :)

Comment: Awesome thanks. It's what I figured, but I'm still getting used to working with sequences of functions and wanted to be sure :)